# GlassFish 4.1 & NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, mysql, windows, netbeans, glassfish

I'm an eclipse(Luna) user. My OS is  Windows 8.1, 64x, and I'm using Java SE 8.  I'm trying to to gain familiarity with the Netbeans IDE, among other Java related technologies that are new to me.

I recently DL NetBeans 8.0.2, with all of the possible plugins/add-ons & started working through some of the Netbeans tutorials.  I have been working through this tutorial currently.  It's one application but build over two sections.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html

In the second section GlassFish server is used.

I DL GlassFish 4.1, installed it, but could not get the server to start.

That problem is detailed here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616668/can-not-start-glassfish-4-1-server-download-unzip-install-windows-8-1?noredirect=1#comment47438028_29616668

I still have not gotten the GlassFish Sever which I DL to start, though, admittedly I have been busy with a lot of other things.

Questions:

1) Since I have DL Netbeans with all plugins, do I need this separate GlassFish DL?  From my readings it would seem, it has already been DL with NetBeans.

2) If it is the case that I do not 'need' the separate GlassFish DL, is there any advantages to having it, reason I should try to get it working vs uninstalling/deleting?

Clearly this is new territory for me, and I'm here to learn so feel free to give me lesson on these technologies & how they work/relate to each other.

Thank you.